# Interactive Brokers API and Web Application

Tags: java, api, web-applications, interactive, broker

We would like to add a feature to the website to enable members to access their Interactive Broker Account directly from our Platform (API http://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/?f=%2Fen%2Fsoftware%2Fibapi.php ).

I believe Trade Work Station (TWS) needs to be up and running when using the API Application.

I see that TWS has a GUI that takes a single username and password (correct?). I am not sure how multiple users can connect, if this really is the case.

My question is, can I use IB API to connect account holders through a 3rd party application?

Please advise.

Thank You

Answer (score 4):

You can now enable IB account holders to log in to IB from your website to connect your platform to the IB API. You can do this with *Brokertron Gateway for IB* (http://www.brokertron.com/gateway/) which allows your users to NOT have to manually launch nor use the GUI of TWS (or IB Gateway).

However your users still need to authenticate/login to IB using their IB credentials (i.e. with IB security device). But now your website (via a Web API) can let users log in to IB so your platform can use the IB API.

I've made the front-end user interface open-source at https://github.com/castedo/brokertron-public so you can integrate the HTML front-end user interface into your website (with the customized front-end calling the Brokertron Gateway for IB Web API).

- Castedo Ellerman (developer of Brokertron Gateway for IB)

Answer (score 0):

Currently (as of Feb 2013) this is not possible: your application would have to connect to TWS via API, you would have to manually launch TWS using client’s credentials (user id, password, 2nd token authentication if applicable).

We have looked into providing programming interface where third parties can offer additional services to our clients similar to what you’ve described, but at the time it did not prove to be worth our investment.

The best way for you to move forward is to submit feature request via our feature poll (http://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/?f=%2Fen%2Fgeneral%2Fpoll%2Findex.php ) , describe your business setup/objective and who you represent, and we’ll evaluate.

- Dennis | Interactive Brokers

Comment: Is it possible for third party app get many users portfolio? As I know, each IB user has to login via gateway so that third party app can access the data via Client Portal Web API, but the gateway only limit 1 user or session. It is not possible that we have to run multiple gateway per 1 user in the cloud server.

Comment: Any update on this. Does IB provide a possibility to do the requested?

Answer (score 0):

There is a headless gateway for interactive broker: https://github.com/ib-controller/ib-controller